# Jenkins run the older code whereas the workspace shows the latest code

Tags: jenkins

I have deployed my code on Jenkins which on a server. Whenever I push the code it runs the previous code and not the new code. I have checked the workspace on the server and it shows the latest code. I am not sure as to how to proceed further with this as I have tried to several steps like:

1. Delete workspace before build starts.
2. Execute Shell -> git pull

If I am missing anything please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the branch.

By default Jenkins will checkout master branch, is it the intended branch? You can change it if needed.

Comment: Well, there is only 1 branch that is the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the advanced git clone behaviours like "Clean before checkout" option in the GIT section? If you share your job configuration, it will be better as I need more background.

Comment: Hi if you can get connected then I could show you the whole of the configuration. My LinkedIn account is https://www.linkedin.com/in/sijo-john-25557b79. Please get connected.